# Can rosbag record and playback action goal?

Tags: rosbag, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am wondering if rosbag is able to record a action goal? Right now, I use moveit to generate a trajectory for pr2 left arm. And I want to record the trajectory and use it again later.

I tried to use rosbag to record the message in topic

```
/l_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/goal
```

and tried to playback the message. I am able to see the playback message using "rostopic echo". However, pr2's left arm didn't move. I guess maybe pr2's left arm controller will only work once it receive a action goal.

Is there anyway to record a action goal?

Following is all topics related to left arm controller.

```
/l_arm_controller/command
/l_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/cancel
/l_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/feedback
/l_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/goal
/l_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/result
/l_arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/status
/l_arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action/cancel
/l_arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action/feedback
/l_arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action/goal
/l_arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action/result
/l_arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action/status
/l_arm_controller/state
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66228/can-rosbag-record-and-playback-action-goal?/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-06-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will have to try this out myself to know for sure. However, you can record the topics being send to the controllers of your pr2 (these can be found in rqt_graph)  and use these.

---

Originally posted by [EdwinvanEmmerik](https://answers.ros.org/users/32311/edwinvanemmerik/) with karma: 115 on 2017-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0